# Enter on Zagg keyboard with iOS causes message to be sent

Tags: ios

I just updated my iPad and now when I hit the enter button it sends messages.  I was used to using it to scroll down. How do I change it back?

Comment: On mac, hitting return sends the message by default. If I hit the option key, it just inserts a return. Have you tried option+return?

Answer (score 1):

Have to use the "cmd" key and enter together for a line space when using message for texting.